# Secure routes & templates with MEAN stack?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

(NOOB ALERT!  Just transitioning from Microsoft to MEAN)

Anyone have an example of a solid pattern for using different routes / layouts / templates with the MEAN stack for public and private areas?  I've experimented with nesting controllers but that brings up questions with the routes.  I'd also prefer to NOT duplicate all of the routes in both Express and the client-side app.  In a perfect scenario, certain relative folders should be considered "private" and others "public" with a different layout (wrapper) for each area.  Users who are not authenticated should be restricted to the public area.

In the non-SPA/MS world, everything is maintained server-side.  There's a certain comfort with securing files, pre-rendering, and the like.  Because of this, I'm noticing a temptation to build out areas using Jade probably more than I should be.  Even as I write this, I'm beginning to feel as if nothing seen by the client should be server side, except for the initial layout and index while using the Node app for routing, data marshaling, and protecting the routes themselves.

Note: Using Passport at the moment for authentication.

Thanks, in advance, for your time and detailed answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick thought:

Serve your partials via get routes with specific folders. For instance, you can have a public and protected folder in your partials folder.

```
-app
  --partials
    ---public
    ---protected
```

Then add authentication middleware on your protected route.

for unprotected:

```
app.get( '/partials/public/*', function(){ //send partial html here } )
```

protected:

```
app.get( '/partials/protected/*', passport.authenticate, function(){ //same as above } )
```

Finally, in your angular application (which hopefully you've set your templateURLs accordingly), add an httpInterceptor to check if the response is a 401, and if so, redirect to the login page -> found here: [Credits to Fredrick Nackstad](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/). Here is the important snippet

```
var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', function($location, $q) {
    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {

        if(response.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/login');
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }

    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
}];

$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

This will allow you to let angular have access the static content, while still having control over what is being served. Hopefully this is helpful.